# View all nodes of a content type using a filter

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type called "Building", which contains a field called "Size". I also have an exposed filter that filters through the size chosen by the user, so the view only displays that size.

What I would like is that the view sorts and displays all the nodes in order of relevancy, i.e. if I choose 5-10 meters, the 5-10 meter buildings show up first, and then the rest of the buildings are also shown.

Thanks, and please feel free to comment critically on this post so I can improve on my questions for the future.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you are providing a contextual filter, the view will render the filtered out result. However, as I understand from your question, you need the entire nodes of that content type with the contextual filter values on the top.

For this you can try using [hook_views_post_execute()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7.x-3.x) where the pre_render() function is yet not called and sort manually. Or, you can use [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x) function to shuffle the result. At this point, you have all the nodes and you can sort them manually.
Hope this is helpful. Thanks